# Unable to get environment variable with node-config in Window (self answer)

Tags: node-config

I'm unable to use [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) to get environment variables in Windows.

My index.js is running a CMD with nodemon.

I've open a new CMD and typed `set myApp_jwtSecretKey=mySecretHere`

```
// config/custom-environment-variables.json
{
  "jwtSecretKey": "myApp_jwtSecretKey"
}
```

```
// index.js
console.log(config.get('myApp_jwtSecretKey'))

// I would expect to see 'mySecretHere' but I get an empty string instead
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi myself from the past!

The reason you are not getting what you'd expect has to do with the `set` command of Windows.

Using `set` the variable is limited to the current command line session.

You need to use `setx` to set variables permanently and so those can share between command line sessions.

In your case, within your CMD, type `setx myApp_jwtSecretKey mySecretHere`